# Angular Custom Filtering by Date Quarter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I've got an array of objects, ng-repeated on the page. I've also got a list of date quarters arrayed in a dropdown select box. If the quarter selected in the dropdown comes later than an item in the ng-repeated list, that item should be filtered out.

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. Here's my HTML:

```
<div ng-app="programApp" ng-controller="programController">
  <select ng-model="advancedFiltersy">
    <option ng-repeat="indexitem in quarters">{{indexitem}}</option>
  </select>
  <div ng-repeat="item in listing | advFilterName:advancedFiltersy:quarters">
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's my Angular Script:

```
angular.module('programApp', ['programApp.controllers','programApp.filters']);
angular.module('programApp.controllers', [])
    .controller('programController', ['$scope', '$filter', 
    function($scope, $filter){
      $scope.advancedFiltersy = 'zeroeth';
      $scope.quarters = ['zeroeth','first','second','third','fourth','fifth','sixth'];
      $scope.listing = [{'name':'aa','aacApprovalIconQuarter':'zeroeth'
      },{'name':'ab','aacApprovalIconQuarter':'first'
      },{'name':'ac','aacApprovalIconQuarter':'second'
      },{'name':'ad','aacApprovalIconQuarter':'third'
      },{'name':'ae','aacApprovalIconQuarter':'fourth'
      },{'name':'af','aacApprovalIconQuarter':'fifth'
      },{'name':'ag','aacApprovalIconQuarter':'sixth'}];
    }]);

angular.module('programApp.filters', []).filter('advFilterName', function(){
    return function(entries, advancedFiltersy, quarters){
        var advFiltered = [];
        angular.forEach(entries, function (entry){
            if(quarters.indexOf(advancedFiltersy) > quarters.indexOf(entry.aacApprovalIconQuarter)){
            }else{
                advFiltered.push(entry);
            };
        });
    };
});
```

None of the ng-repeated items are ever showing, so the filter isn't working properly. What do I need to do to get the filter working?

**Here's a Codepen of it: http://codepen.io/trueScript/pen/MwbVpO**

Answer (score 1):

You still need to return the value of the filtered results:

```
angular.module('programApp.filters', []).filter('advFilterName', function(){
    return function(entries, advancedFiltersy, quarters){
        var advFiltered = [];
        angular.forEach(entries, function (entry){
            if(quarters.indexOf(advancedFiltersy) > quarters.indexOf(entry.aacApprovalIconQuarter)){
            }else{
                advFiltered.push(entry);
            };
        });
        // Fix
        return advFiltered;
    };
});
```

Fixed here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVbdQo?editors=101