# How to display data in a repository based on the quarter of the year?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to sort data using angularJS by the quarter of the year on a premade widget through the CMS of a website. I've created the widgets, the data pulled is everything from a specific repository. I only want to pull items per quarter. Current quarter and then the last 3 quarters individually. I am new to angularJS so I'm not even sure where to start.
I've tried a few solutions from stack overflow but they cause the website to stop loading.
I hope this makes sense, very new to this language, kind of not sure where to start. The example code I was using was [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30469577/angular-custom-filtering-by-date-quarter]

this is what it's supposed to look like. I can style it, not the issue. It's the backend I'm having trouble with.
[screenshot of how the widget(s) should look. I've already written the widgets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp3AO.png)

Comment: Chrome DevTools will give you more information if you're getting exceptions as a result of incorrect code. We need some more details on the issue you're having.

Comment: My problem is all the examples I see online are from people who are providing their own information, normally in an array, and then filtering that data as needed but my problem is my data isn't in an array. It's being pulled from a repository after a query is run. I'm just not sure how to create a filter or how to implement it.

Comment: @Shardae8806 if you post an example of the data and what you have tried so far we can help further